# Better way of defining similar variables at once (Python 2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm solving a problem that requires me to convert each alphabet of a 9 letter string into a variable.

This is the current code

```
number = input("Enter a nine-digit number here \n")

string = str(number)

d1 = string[0]
d2 = string[1]
d3 = string[2]
d4 = string[3]
d5 = string[4]
d6 = string[5]
d7 = string[6]
d8 = string[7]
d9 = string[8]
```

Is there a better way of defining all of these variables?

It just felt like there should be but I couldn't think of how.

Comment: Does your problem really "require" this?  Why can't you just store them in a list, dict or string, and access them as d[1], d[2], etc.?

Comment: There is no such thing as a problem requiring such weird approach, @happydave is right, you should use arrays

Comment: For reasons of security use `raw_input()` in Python 2.x instead of `input()`. Please revisit the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Since a string is a sequence you can perform sequence unpacking on it but it'll still force you to use several variables.

```
a = str(1234)
b,c,d,e = a
>> b
>> '1'
>> c
>> '2'
```

and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

You can already index the string:

```
>>> s = '123456789'
>>> s[4]
'5'
```

so there really isn't any need for a separate variable for each character. Should you decide that a list of integers is a better data structure for your purposes, then there is a nice solution in:

```
>>> s = '123456789'
>>> d = [int(s_digit) for s_digit in s]
>>> d
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the exec function. Your code could be like this:

```
for index, value in enumerate(string):
    exec ('d' + str(index) + '= string[' + str(index) + ']')
```

However the exec function should be used with care.

Answer (score 0):

If `string` is exactly 9 characters, this code works:

```
d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6,d7,d8,d9 = string
```

Answer (score -1):

This is elegant but dangerous:

```
count=1
for x in string:
   locals()["d%d"%(count)] = x
   count += 1
```

This will fool IDE's and cause other problems, but is great if the string is longer than 9 characters, and shows the general approach of programmatically assigning a bunch of variables...